# Swift UI Firebase AddSnapShotListeners

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, swiftui

I am seeing the Firebase call for addSnapshotListener a lot ever since I started learning Swift UI and I don't understand the purpose of using it. I know it is used for observing changes or something along those lines but I don't know exactly what it is or when to use it in Swift UI. Any help, or helpful definitions or examples of when it would be a proper time to use it? Thanks.

Comment: Just try to search https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswiftui%5D+addSnapshotListener

Comment: This article answers your question: [SwiftUI: Fetching Data from Firestore in Real Time](https://peterfriese.dev/swiftui-firebase-fetch-data/). Happy to answer more specific questions (update your question or reply to this comment).

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a travel list app. Say all your data save in Firestore. When you add new trip you can send to Firestore and Firestore will save and push to you by addSnapshotListener that new added trip then you can insert that trip in your client travel list.
Or Chat app. Two client can communicate with addSnapshotListener.